# Opening a view controller on clicking the notification in the status bar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have developed an app which uses local notification. so a notification is triggered in the status bar once I press a button. after coming out of the app, if I press the notification in the status bar it takes me to the page where I left. but I want it to take to a particular view controller. Please give some solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some special JSON in the local notification payload that doesn't show up in the User. Something like:

`'PushToViewController':'X'`

To do this, create a `NSDictionary` like so and attach it to your local notification:

```
    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"ViewControllerName"
                                                       forKey:@"PushToViewController"];
    localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;
```

Then in your `AppDelegate` you'll need to do two things. First, you need to get the UILocalNotification in `AppDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in case your user clicked on the notification when the app was closed/killed. The second is to implement `DidReceiveLocalNotification`, which will fire if the app is in the background when they select the notification.

In both cases, you can get the localnotification and get the dictionary by doing

```
NSDictionary *infoDict =  [notification.userInfo];
```

Now you have access to which VC you want to push to.

Comment: I am new to IOS. Can you please explain your answer in detail.

Comment: @Bhavna This should serve as a guide for what you can google/search for. There are dozens of tutorials out there on step-by-step instructions to implement custom payload notifications and how to intercept those in your app. I highlighted the delegate methods you need to pay attention to. StackOverflow is not meant to be a place for custom-written step-by-step tutorials for widely explained topics. Best of luck.